# Паттерн "Песочница". Почему некоторые вещи реализованы именно так?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования

Паттерн взят из книги Стефана Стоянова "JavaScript patterns". Автор описывает паттерн "Песочница" примерно так:

1. Обращаемся к функции-конструктору всего приложения, при этом в параметры передаем все необходимые для работы модули в виде массива и последним параметром - callback-функцию.

   ```
   Sandbox(['ajax', 'event'], function (box) {
    // console.log(box);
   });
   ```

   При этом имена модулей можно передавать в виде отдельных аргументов (строк):

   ```
   Sandbox('ajax', 'dom', function (box) {
    // console.log(box);
   });
   ```

   Также можно либо передать "wilcard", либо вообще ничего кроме функции-callback'а не передать, чтобы автоматически загрузить все возможные модули:

   ```
   Sandbox('*', function (box) {
    // console.log(box);
   });

   Sandbox(function (box) {
    // console.log(box);
   });
   ```
2. Конструктор выглядит следующим образом:

   ```
   function Sandbox() {
       // turning arguments into an array
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), // the last argument is the callback
       callback = args.pop(), // modules can be passed as an array or as individual parameters
       modules = (args[0] && typeof args[0] === "string") ? args : args[0], i;
       // make sure the function is called
       // as a constructor
       if (!(this instanceof Sandbox)) {
           return new Sandbox(modules,callback);
       }
       // add properties to `this` as needed:
       this.a = 1;
       this.b = 2;
       // now add modules to the core `this` object
       // no modules or "*" both mean "use all modules"
       if (!modules || modules === '*') {
           modules = [];
           for (i in Sandbox.modules) {
               if (Sandbox.modules.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                   modules.push(i);
               }
           }
       }
       // initialize the required modules
       for (i = 0; i < modules.length; i += 1) {
           Sandbox.modules[modules[i]](this);
       }
       // call the callback
       callback(this);
   }
   // any prototype properties as needed
   Sandbox.prototype = {
       name: "My Application",
       version: "1.0",
       getName: function() {
           return this.name;
       }
   };
   ```

Непонятно следующее:

1. Зачем callback вызывается именно как `callback(this)`? Ведь можно, например, вызвать его так: `callback.call(this)`, и тогда внутри анонимной функции, переданной в параметр конструктора можно будет не обращаться к переменной (`box`), чтобы получить доступ к свойствам объекта, а просто использовать `this`.
2. Зачем вообще использовать callback в данном случае? Почему нельзя просто создать объект при помощи конструктора, передав ему необходимые модули в качестве аргументов, а позже обращаться к созданным объектам "как всегда"?

   ```
   let a = new Sandbox(['ajax', 'event']);
   a.publicMethod();
   ```

В целом, автор описывает преимущества так (вольный перевод):

> 1. Используя паттерн "Песочница", вы не оставляете следов в глобальном пространстве имён.
> 2. Если необходимо, вы можете использовать тот факт, что функции являются объектами и хранить некоторые данные как "статические"
>      свойства конструктора `Sandbox()`.
> 3. И, наконец, у вас могут быть разные инстансы (в зависимости от подключенных модулей), которые работают независимо друг от друга.

Но каждое из этих "преимуществ" я могу оспорить:

1. Я могу с таким же успехом, не используя данный паттерн, завернуть весь свой код в самоисполняющееся функциональное выражение, создав тем самым отдельный scope, не засоряя глобальное пространство имен.
2. А не используя "Песочницу" не могу?
3. То же самое, но не используя "Песочницу", я описал в двух строках кода чуть выше.

В общем, интересующие меня вопросы с точки зрения реализации отдельных элементов кода я задал чуть выше. Остался лишь один вопрос: а действительно ли этот паттерн решает те проблемы, которые он берется решить?

Comment: Вы правы. И автор прав. Вы можете решить проблему засорения глобального пространства имен завернув ваш код в **IIFE**. Но и песочница решает ту же проблему. Что я хочу сказать - подход "песочницы" просто один из нескольких подходов. Вы можете его использовать, а можете и не использовать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko осталось только с деталями реализации разобраться.

Comment: Ну а вообще "песочница" - довольно не плохой паттерн. Например, `angular` так работает.